# What's the name of the tape used on laptop heat sinks?

Tags: fan, heatsink, tape

I recently swapped my laptop's fan with a new one...I used a glue stick to glue back the tape on the new fan...However, I am not really sure if the glue stick can withstand heat or if it doesn't dry up quickly...

So I am looking to buy a tape, However I don't know the name of the tape I am supposed to buy...what's the name of the tape circled in red in the following three pictures ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for *kapton* tape, which comes in various sizes and colors. It's heavily used in electronics manufacturing and repair.

Comment: i am pretty sure now that it is gaffer tape...Is Kapton tape a good alternative ? isn't Kapton tape used for the circuit board ? would it be appropriate for taping the fan to the heatsink ?

Comment: I've used kapton tape with success for various projects, but bear in mind that tape and adhesive quality may vary a lot. If you go cheap you might get disappointed. It handles well temperature variations, so I suggest you give it a try.